# How to translate the following SQL to Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I am using `IQueryable<T>` interface.

How can I translate the following sql statement to `IQueryable`?

```
select * from customer
where joindate > DateTime.Now and
      (customertype = 'system' or customerstatus = 'active') and
      customerlocation = 'europe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this :

```
    var result = from record in context.customer 
    where record.joindate > DateTime.Now && 
        (record.customertype == "system" || record.customerstatus == "active") && 
        record.customerlocation == "europe"
    select record
```

There is a nice tool, Linqer, which can help you to convert SQL queries to LINQ. Of course for such simple cases it is overkill, but you can consider it for heavy queries of course if you are more familiar with SQL.

You can find it here [LINQER](http://www.sqltolinq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = 
from i in db.customer
where i.joindate > DateTime.Now 
&& (i.customertype == 'system' || i.customerstatus == 'active')
&& i.customerlocation == 'europe'
select i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var queryable = Customers.Where(x=>x.joindate > now && (x.customertype == "system" || x.customerstatus == "active") && x.customerlocation == "europe")
```

I can't remember if linq will evaluate DateTime.Now so I just threw it into a variable ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I pefer the following syntax but you could use query syntax as well:

```
var results = yourContext.Customers.Where(c => (c.JoinDate > DateTime.Now) &&
    ((c.CustomerType.Equals("system") || (c.CustomerType.Equals("active")) &&
    (c.CustomerLocation.Equals("europe")));
```

Using query syntax:

```
var results = from c in yourContext.Customers
    where (c.JoinDate > DateTime.Now) &&
    (c.CustomerType.Equals("system") || c.CustomerStatus.Equals("active")) &&
    c.CustomerLocation.Equals("europe")
    select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from c in customer
              where (c.joindate > DateTime.Now) &&
                    (c.customertype == "system" || c.customerstatus == "active") &&
                    (c.customerlocation == "europe")
              select c)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: you don't put customerlocation == 'europe'